# Source a file inside golang and run a command before each listed line

Tags: shell, go

Inside a golang program i want to source a file (in this case its `.clean`) which would look like this

```
$HOME/directory1
$HOME/directory1/.directory2
$HOME/directory3
```

and then run the `rm -rf` command before each directory.
Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a [`bufio.Scanner`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner).

**Bold text** added by me.

> Scanner provides a convenient interface for reading data such as a file of newline-delimited lines of text. Successive calls to the Scan method will step through the 'tokens' of a file, skipping the bytes between the tokens. The specification of a token is defined by a split function of type SplitFunc; **the default split function breaks the input into lines with line termination stripped.** Split functions are defined in this package for scanning a file into lines, bytes, UTF-8-encoded runes, and space-delimited words. The client may instead provide a custom split function.

Example using [`os.RemoveAll()`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#RemoveAll):

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open(".clean")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    s := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for s.Scan() {
        fmt.Println("Deleting:", s.Text())
        if err := os.RemoveAll(s.Text()); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }
    if err := s.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/dxpwFNYAwb)

Or, using [`Cmd.Run()` from `os/exec`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Run) to run `rm -rf`:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("file.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    s := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    for s.Scan() {
        fmt.Println("Deleting:", s.Text())
        cmd := exec.Command("rm", "-rf", s.Text())
        if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    }
    if err := s.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/pfKxkNgpAH)

Comment: @theallegedjosh, note that the suggested program *as is,* won't do much interesting using your file because that file contains references to environment variables. Hence you will either have to somehow preprocess it to detect and expand those variables or take one of two alternate routes: 1) `exec` not just `rm` but `/bin/sh -c 'rm -rf " + s.Text() + `"'; 2) start a shell process and send to its standard input each line extracted from your file *prefixed* with `rm -rf ` -- this way the shell will be started just once which is a performance win

Comment: @theallegedjosh, note that @konsolebox's suggestion might be used as a an extension to the second approach I proposed; the course of action would be: 1) Create a temporary file (using `syscall.Mktemp()` or something like this); 2) Run the shell passing it the file name of that script as a parameter; 3) Just *connect* the opened file to the shell process' `cmd.Stdin` variable -- without parsing or modifying it in any way; and the script passed to the shell will take care of the rest; 4) Delete the temporary script file when it's done.

Comment: @kostix Very good point, I didn't take environment variables into account, I only tested the code with static paths.

Comment: @kostix I've updated the first example replacing `os.Remove()` with `os.RemoveAll()` which gets around this problem from a Go POV, but you are still correct with regards to the original requirement of prefacing each line with `rm -rf`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "sourcing" the file, you could instead just read it:

```
while IFS= read TARGET; do
    rm -fr "${TARGET/'$HOME'/$HOME}"
done < .clean
```

You can also add checks to it like skipping comments:

```
while read TARGET; do  ## Explicitly do not change IFS to exclude leading and trailing spaces.
    case "$TARGET" in
    \#*)
        # Skip comments.
        ;;
    *)
        rm -fr "${TARGET/'$HOME'/$HOME}"
        ;;
    esac
done < .clean
```

If you need more compatibility i.e. it doesn't support `${PARAM/X/Y}` expansion method, just used sed anyway:

```
rm -fr "$(echo "$TARGET" | sed "s|\$HOME|$HOME|")"  ## No 'g'. I doubt it's sensible to have two `$HOME`'s.
```

Comment: im talking about placing `rm -rf` before each direcory inside of the golang program

Comment: Oh. Well your descriptions are still misleading. Mind updating more info on how it should be done?